# how to display listview items, when a user enter some number in textbox?

Tags: java, android, listview

**how to display listview items in android, when a user enter some number in edittext and click on a button to display the specified number of list items on the next activity ?**

I have one EditText and a Button on MainActivity1 and a ListView and TextView on MainActivity2. TextView is just for letting me know tht value is passing on next screen.

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.populatelist;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myin = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                myin.putExtra("textbox", edt.getText().toString());
                startActivity(myin);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> MainActivity2.java

```
package com.populatelist;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        Intent myin2 = getIntent();
        String str = myin2.getStringExtra("textbox");

        tv.setText(str);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String[] arrStr = new String[] {
                "Hello World",
                "Hello India",
                "Hello Rajasthan",
                "Hello Jodhpur",
                "Hello Mujeeb"
        };

        final List<String> hello_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrStr));

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hello_list);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(str);

            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: this code is fine i just stuck here..how to implement the logic to display the items of list view on a user given number !

Comment: so u want a list item according to your input right??

Comment: @mohammad yes exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the coming value at last of your string array like

```
String[] arrStr = new String[] {
                "Hello World",
                "Hello India",
                "Hello Rajasthan",
                "Hello Jodhpur",
                "Hello Mujeeb",
                str
        };
```

It will show your input value to last position of your listview.

And if you want to add new items and show old as well then you have to pass whole string array to previous activity and add new value to last position, pass it when start next activity. By using this you can see all data on listview.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get value in second activity create a new array "b" with required no of values.

```
String str = myin2.getStringExtra("textbox");
int noOfNames = Integer.parseInt(str);
String[] b = new String[StringnoOfNames];
```

Then copy the items from the original array

```
b = Arrays.copyOf(arrStr, noOfNames);
final List<String> hello_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, validate if your EditText isn't null, here your app may crash

```
if (edt.getText().length() > 0) {

        Intent myin = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
        myin.putExtra("textbox", Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(myin);
    }
```

Then handle your intent

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;
    int number = intent.getIntExtra("textbox", 0);
    switch (number) {

        case 0:

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrStr);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case 1:

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AnotherSourceArray);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case 2:

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AnotherSourceArray);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

            ...

        default:

            break;
    }
```

Note - this is just sample. You can resolve this on many another ways. Each switch case may contain another data to display. Using default layouts for listviews may be frustrating, better way is to create custom class which `extends ArrayAdapter<String>`